# How to get the primary key id that is auto generated in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I have a DB Schema that I have inherited from some legacy code. Now we intend to use Django to reflect the tables into models. This means I cannot have the tables be generated using the django models. The table schema looks like so:-

```
mysql> desc student_profile;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| joining_on  | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| brothername | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now the Django model that I have created for this schema looks like this:-

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    joining_on=models.DateField()
    brothername=models.CharField(max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        db_table="student_profile"
```

When I insert a row into this, like so:-

```
StudentProfile.objects.insert(brothername="Bro")
```

The row is correctly inserted. But I do not have a way to extract the id field. It appears that since this field is not an `AutoField`, django does not copy over the id that was automatically generated by MySql. What can I do to obtain the `id` value with which the row was created? I checked (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8799#comment:1), and this appears to be by design. But I still need a way to get to the `id` and have it be reflected in the `StudentProfile` model. What can I do?

One solution could be to override the default `save()` and explicitly provide the `id` into the `save()` of the model. But is that the right way? The database (it is MySql) provides a way to generate the id, and I must be able to use this fact to my advantage rather than having to maintain a running counter by the application. Any hints?

Comment: What happens if you don't define the `id` field in your model at all?

Comment: If I do not do that then Django created a field automatically of the type project.app.StudentProfile.id or something like that. Clearly my underlying schema does not have this named as a column. In short, I want everything that Django's `AutoField` provides, just that I want the name to be mine.

Comment: Django will create a column named `id` by default which is the same as your legacy column. `project.app.StudentProfile.id` is the field name in your Python code, it is not the database colum name. Are you sure it does not work this way?

Comment: Hey, yes, that worked. I had assumed incorrectly. Thanks, I will mark this as the right answer after more look in.

Comment: [django extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graph_models.html) has a command to do this pip install django-extensions manage.py graph_models --pygraphviz -a -g -o my_project_visualized.png

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can skip defining the `id` column altogether, ie:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    # id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    joining_on=models.DateField()
    brothername=models.CharField(max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        db_table="student_profile"
```

Django will create or use an autoincrement column named `id` by default, which is the same as your legacy column.

If the column name was different, you could use an `AutoField` with a different name, such as:

```
my_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```